# problem with kb4011645 and how to uninstall this patch

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, word, patching

today I've installed [KB4011645](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011645/january-9-2018-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2016-kb4011645) update for SharePoint Server 2016. And now I regret it and wants that update to be removed. Could someone here know how to do that? According to this [SharePoint Server 2013 – Can you uninstall patches?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/george_bethanis/2014/08/28/sharepoint-server-2013-can-you-uninstall-patches/), you can't do it.

Why I wants this patch to be removed. This patch made me unable to open any docx from SharePoint library. [image: This is the message that I got when it open]
Before this patch I was able to open it.

**Edited to Add more information on the problem**

I've written my problem to [msdn](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a002a78-f2d2-4e15-8830-c464f96513df/kb4011645-couldnt-open-word-docx-from-sharepoint-2016-library?forum=sharepointadmin). Here's the problem and summary.

1. The problem still exist even after running SP configuration wizard (see point 2nd).
2. the problem didn't appear after doing iisreset. Word asked for credential to open the document.
3. but if I closed word and reopened the same document, It failed again. And this time it didn't ask for credential.
4. checking on fiddler log, it did receive 401.
   [image: fiddler log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolve after I did **Reset Internet Explorer Settings** and also checked **Delete personal settings** under Internet Options Advanced tab and restart windows.
I guest I must had made something wrong in setting the internet options and those patch made it even worst or better.

reference thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3670082d-c7b2-44cb-9ee4-180e88c3f2dc/microsoft-word-error-when-trying-to-open-a-document-in-sharepoint-2013-could-not-open?forum=sharepointgeneral#f20772f5-26ad-4971-bf04-cc91ce122784

Answer (score 2):

You cannot uninstall sharepoint patch. Only way to deal with that is to have full VM and DB backup to restore to point in time before the update.

Please note that running psconfig is necessary after the CU Upgrade. Always run it using the Gui as per Stefan Grossner recommendation: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/08/20/why-i-prefer-psconfigui-exe-over-psconfig-exe/